# finding the expected value for $a_{n}=\frac{1+i}{2+n}$

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

i am trying to find the expected value of $$a_{n}=\frac{1+i}{2+n}$$ where the pmf is given by $$\binom {n}{i}\frac{(2i-1)!!((2(n-i)-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$$

$$E(a_{n})=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1+i}{2+n}\binom {n}{i}\frac{(2i-1)!!((2(n-i)-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$$
$$=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1+i}{2+n}\frac{1}{4^{n}}\binom{2i}{i}\binom{2(n-i)}{n-i}$$
this is what i did so far and got stuck

Comment: Try to compute the very first terms $(n=1,2,3,4)$. The pattern is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$$\sum_{i+j=n}i\binom{2i}i\binom{2j}j=\sum_{i+j=n}j\binom{2i}i\binom{2j}j$$and:$$\sum_{i+j=n}i\binom{2i}i\binom{2j}j+\sum_{i+j=n}j\binom{2i}i\binom{2j}j=n\sum_{i+j=n}\binom{2i}i\binom{2j}j$$

So that $$\sum_{i+j=n}i\binom{2i}i\binom{2j}j=\frac12n\sum_{i+j=n}\binom{2i}i\binom{2j}j$$